# how to update the data in firebase database, instead of creating a new data, using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using reactjs along with firebase database for storing 'to-do' item. I can successfully store objects n firebase database. But, how to update a particular object in firebase database.

My 'to-do' component where I store object in firebase database.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { userRef } from '../firebase.js';

    class Todo extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          todotitle: ''
        }
      }

      StoreTitle(){
        userRef.push({
          title: {this.state.title}
        })
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div className="form-group sign-in">
            <div className="input-group">
              <input 
                type="text" 
                value = {this.state.todotitle}
                placeholder="enter a text for to-do"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={event => this.setState({email: event.target.value })}
               />
               <button 
                  type="submit" 
                  className="btn btn-md btn-primary sign-in-button"
                  onClick={() => this.storeTitle()}
                >
                  Post
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>  
        )
      }
```

My todo-update component, where I need to update a particular object instead of creating a new object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { userRef } from '../firebase.js';

class Todoupdate extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todotitle: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    userRef.on('value', data => {
      this.setState({todotitle: data.val()})
    })
  }

  updateTitle(){
    // to update todo title 
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="form-group sign-in">
        <div className="input-group">
          <textarea
            value = {this.state.todotitle}
            className="form-control"
            onChange={event => this.setState({email: event.target.value })}
           />
           <button 
              type="submit" 
              className="btn btn-md btn-primary sign-in-button"
              onClick={() => this.updateTitle()}
            >
              Post
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    )
  }
```

How to update using an object that's been already stored in firebase database.

Comment: Why don't you just create one component with a store and update function?

Answer (score 0):

**I would try it similar to this:**

1) Create array for all the todos in your main components state

2) In your main component load all the todos from firebase and save them in your array.

3) For each todo render a new component and set all the props needed, also give it a function to change in the main component.

4) Your child just displays the data given by the props. OnClick you execute the functions in the parent/main component.

5) Update firebase and the state.

**Disclaimer:**

I don't really know firebase, but I think this link provides you with the needed information. https://time2hack.com/2017/02/firebase-crud-operations-javascript-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, you were modifying a different key—of `email`—in your state instead of the `todotitle`. Since you're pulling in `todotitle` to your textarea, that's probably the key you want to update in your state.

To change something in your Firebase database, use `.update()` on your `userRef` with that passing an object with the location/name (of the key you're updating in your database) as the key, and the new data as the value, so in this case `{ todotitle: this.state.todotitle }`.

You can update nested data by formatting the key like so: `['/projects/todotitle']:`
or even include variables, like: `` [`/projects/${this.props.projectId}/todotitle`]: ``

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { userRef } from '../firebase.js';

class Todoupdate extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todotitle: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    userRef.on('value', data => {
      this.setState({todotitle: data.val()})
    })
  }

  updateTitle(){
    userRef.update({ todotitle: this.state.todotitle });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="form-group sign-in">
        <div className="input-group">
          <textarea
            value = {this.state.todotitle}
            className="form-control"
            onChange={event => this.setState({todotitle: event.target.value })}
           />
           <button 
              type="submit" 
              className="btn btn-md btn-primary sign-in-button"
              onClick={() => this.updateTitle()}
            >
              Post
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    )
  }
```